# Add Login and logout buttons to top menu bar

Tags: functions, login, sub-menu, logout

I got this code to insert menu bar in the PRIMARY menubar, but I can not find a way to insert it into my secondary, or top menubar above the primary menu bar.
Could anyone teach me how to do that?

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'menu_top') {
      $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Log Out</a></li>';
    }
    elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'menu_top') {
      $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

=============Additional Info==============
I am using Custom Community Theme 1.4. Just in case it will be helpful, and **I tried to use 'menu_top' as keyword rather than primary, but it does not work, it originally was primary!**

==============MORE INFO====================
Ok, in request, I found more info, but as I tried, menu_top does not work, and seem these code already tell what is the name of the menu, is that right?

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'menu_top' => __('Header top menu', 'cc'),
        'primary' => __('Header bottom menu', 'cc'),
    ));
```

Comment: never mind, I realized that its due to the fact the theme will ROLL back to certain ...place that menu will not display unless there is at least 1 item setup in the menus.

Answer (score 1):

"PRIMARY" and "secondary" menu bar really don't mean anything when used out of context and without explanation. However, (guessing a lot) if your menus are constructed consistently you should be able to find the 'name' of the second menu and add a condition like (overly formatted for readability):

```
if (
  is_user_logged_in() 
  && (
    $args->theme_location == 'menu_top' 
    || $args->theme_location == 'other_menu_name'
  )
) { 
    $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url() .'">Log Out</a></li>';
```

Same with the `elseif`.

Look for a call to [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) in your theme files to find the 'name' of the second menu.

Comment: I added more info, sry for letting you guess so much lol, but I do not konw why the name is not working when I use them, though.